# Google App Indexing not working in some devices

Tags: android, google-search-console, deep-linking, android-app-indexing, google-search-platform

I am working with Google App Indexing.

The app indexing working fine with ASUS Zenfone 2(Android version 4.4.2).
But not working with the following devices which are all made test with.

1. Samsung Google/Galaxy Nexus 
   a) Android version : 4.2.1
   b) Google App version - 4.3.10..
2. LGE Nexus 
   a) Android version : 5.0.1
   b) Google App Version - 4.3.10..
3. LGE Nexus 5
   a) Android version : 5.0.1
   b) Google App Version - 4.3.10..

In Asus, search result showing the result with my app icon. When clicking the result its navigating to correct app page.

But in others not showing the search result as like ASUS.
And I am got the warning mail from webmaster.

```
When indexing the deep links to your app, we detected that the content of 15 app pages doesn’t match the content of the corresponding web page. This is a bad experience for your users because they won’t find what they were looking for on your app page. We won’t show deep links for these app pages in our smartphone search results. This is an important issue that needs your immediate attention.
```

Could you guess what the things going wrong ?
If you need more details will provide on possible situation.

Comment: Can you pls confirm you're using the same user account, you're signed in, etc. on the devices where you don't see the deep links? Wanted to make sure the environment is consistent across these devices.